# Machine Learning for medical researchers

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, data-mining, data-science-model

My friend is a medical researcher and he want to use machine learning for prediction.

Is there any one who is not a computer science person and he learnt programming and machine learning in a very short time? And how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He can use  no-code ML platforms such as: RapidMiner Studio, Google ML Kit, Orange, and BigML.

Also, this article is very good article for learning RapidMiner

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/machine-learning-for-programmers-and-non-programmers-f8568d357750

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Machine Learning is not something that can be mastered or learnt in a short time, and you need at least 3-4 months familiarize yourself with the basics and even after that you need at least 6-7 months to get to a good place with your ML knowledge.

- To get started you can first go through this course ([Python for
  Everybody - Full University Python Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8DvywoWv6fI)) to familiarize
  yourself with python and learn the basics of programming.
- After this, you need to know basic statistics, linear algebra and
  basic differential calculus. You can learn these 3 subjects from this
  course on Linear Algebra from [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra), this course on
  [Statistics from freecodecamp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxpc-HPKN28&list=PLWKjhJtqVAbl5SlE6aBHzUVZ1e6q1Wz0v&index=4) and this course on [Calculus from
  Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/calculus-1) Leave the "Integration" sections you won't need them
  much.

Now the above 2 points only cover the pre-requisites to get started with machine learning. From here to get started with ML follow the following list of courses:

- Machine Learning by Andrew Ng (Stanford University) [Link](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning?): To get to know the inner workings and inner maths of all the major machine learning algorithms. The only downside of this course is that the implementation of all machine learning algorithms is on Matlab.
- Machine Learning A-Z (Udemy) [Link](https://www.udemy.com/course/machinelearning/): This course will explain the implementation of machine learning algorithms in python. And would help you to create basic machine learning projects.

The above courses will get you started in machine learning, and you will have good knowledge of how ML learning algorithms work. After this comes, Deep Learning, currently most research work is being conducted in deep learning, deep learning algorithms offer highly efficient mathematical and statistical method the get good accuracy from your data. To get started with deep learning these 2 specializations of Coursera are more than enough to give you a working mathematical and implementational knowledge in Deep Learning. The 2 courses are as follows:

- Deep Learning Specialization from Deeplearning.ai [Link](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/deep-learning?): This course will give you a good mathematical knowledge related to deep learning.

Tensorflow Developer Specialization from Deeplearning.ai [Link](https://www.coursera.org/professional-certificates/tensorflow-in-practice?): This course will teach you how to implement basic neural networks and teach you the implementation of deep learning in Tensorflow framework.

PS: Please pardon my English if it is not up to the mark. This is my first answer so please go easy on me XP.